# Oracle Query not Working

Tags: sql, oracle

**oracle query** is not working. Please specify what is wrong in this query?

```
(select hacker_id,challenge_id, max(score) as soc 
 from submissions 
 group by hacker_id,challenge_id 
 having max(score)>0) t2;
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO.  Please take some time to read [ask]. How would we know what is wrong with this query?  You do not provide example table data or expected output.  WHat does "not working" mean?  People here are not mind readers.

Comment: It seems like it is a part of some subquery, hence partial query. no table level info provided.

Comment: Are you getting an error or getting the wrong results? How does this fit into the overall query/

Answer (score 1):

Please read @OldProgrammer comments. Anyway, I think this should work for you

```
select hacker_id,challenge_id, max(score) as soc 
   from submissions 
  group by hacker_id,challenge_id 
  having max(score)>0;
```